# Why won't my UIImageView appear as a subview?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"popup.png"];
  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

  [self.view addSubview:imageView];

  [image release];
  [imageView release];
```

The code sits within a UIViewcontroller object. It compiles fine but, when run, the subview does not appear to be added.

I'm tired.

Answer (score 1):

`initWithContentsOfFile` requires the complete file path, not just the file name.

Replace the line where you initialize UIImage with the following:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [bundle pathForResource:@"popup" ofType:@"png"]];
```

A simpler way will be to use the `imageNamed:` method of the UIImage class

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popup.png"]];
```

And you dont have to worry about the path-to-file details. Just that the `initWithImage:` method caches the image. Depending upon your application might be good or bad idea.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"popup.png"];
```

and, off course, get rid of the `[image release];` because in this solution the `image` is autoreleased.

Notice that this solution won't be good if you have more than one image with this name (in different folders/groups)...

Answer (score 0):

your imageView needs a frame. 

`imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old now, but some users can still benefit from an answer.

Like others have said, try using  `[UIImage imagedNamed:]` instead of `initWithContentsOfFile`.

And the reason it is not showing up on screen is you did not set a location for the image. You can fix this by either setting a frame for the image view or setting its center at a single point. To place the image view in the center of the screen:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

imageView.center = [self.view center];

// or if you want to set a frame instead
// CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
// [imageView setFrame:imageFrame];

[self.view addSubView:imageView];
```

Enjoy :)